# Ip телевидение

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php, mysql

Сейчас провайдеры поставляют и интернет телевидение для пользователей (ip tv). Я хочу создать сайт, который бы позволял пользователю(если он конечно оплатил своему провайдеру услугу ip tv), смотреть эти каналы через браузер. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать, может быть есть какие нибудь статьи на эту тему? Желательно русскоязычные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотри в сторону технологии [OTT (Over the Top)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTT)

См. также

[How to build a Netflix-like multiscreen OTT service (part 1)](http://blog.eltrovemo.com/600/how-to-build-a-netflix-like-multiscreen-ott-service-part-1/)

[How to build a Netflix-like multiscreen OTT service (part 2)](http://blog.eltrovemo.com/785/how-to-build-a-netflix-like-multiscreen-ott-service-part-2/)